# How to assign a list that is set as a variable to another list (python)

Tags: python

In building a config file, I'm trying to add a list to another list. I'd rather not use any functions like append or python logic in this config file. Some examples are listed below:

```
config = {
        'users': [
                'user1',
                'user2',
                'user3'
        ]
}

admin_access = {
        'allowed_users': [
                config['users'],
                'adminuser1',
                'adminuser2'
        ]
}
```

Am I going about this the right way or am I completely off?

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: This kind of looks like it would be working

Comment: Why not just run your code and look at the output... Here `admin_access` = `{'allowed_users': [['user1', 'user2', 'user3'], 'adminuser1', 'adminuser2']}`

Comment: Are you want this output `{'allowed_users': ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'adminuser1', 'adminuser2']}`or above

Comment: Solution found by @BeRT2me via the * prefix operator which unpacks the list!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you may be looking for is:

```
admin_access = {
        'allowed_users': [
                *config['users'],
                'adminuser1',
                'adminuser2'
        ]
}
```

Which gives:

```
{'allowed_users': ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'adminuser1', 'adminuser2']}
```

---

If you couldn't directly create `admin_access` like this, you could also add on the wanted list like this:

```
# Given
config = {'users': ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']}
admin_access = {'allowed_users': ['adminuser1', 'adminuser2']}

# Do
admin_access['allowed_users'] += config['users']

# Outputs
print(admin_access)
{'allowed_users': ['adminuser1', 'adminuser2', 'user1', 'user2', 'user3']}
```

Comment: This is exactly what is needed! Thank you very much! Can you give a brief explanation about why that works or what it does?

Comment: The asterisk is an unpacking operator in this context

Comment: Much appreciated @LancelotduLac, that's what I was wondering about!

Comment: A lot of places only reference the `*` operator in the context of functions, but [this article](https://geekflare.com/python-unpacking-operators/) Does a good job of explaining it in the context of lists and dicts as well~

Comment: Understood, I'll go over that article, thanks again @BeRT2me!